# raising events passing parameters in wpf

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I'd like to add tabs to my window when an item in the GridView is double-clicked. But the tab that will be added depends on the clicked item. Which way should I do this on WPF? I thought about RoutedEvents, but I don't know how to pass a parameter with it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use commands rather than routed events:

Set a command for the clicked item and pass the clicked item's reference as the command's parameter using RelativeSource binding in the XAML.

Answer (score 6):

[This codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF3.aspx) covers using a new `RoutedEvent` with a different argument type than just `RoutedEventArgs` (rather far down, search for "Second using custom RoutedEventArgs"), though I wish WPF included a version of `RoutedEventHandler` like the CLR's `EventHandler<T> where T : EventArgs` so you didn't have to declare a new delegate every time.

The summary:

- Create a new type that subtypes RoutedEventArgs and has properties for your data.
- Make sure your RoutedEventArgs subtype implements the non-default constructors of RoutedEventArgs as those are needed for it to work.
- Declare a new delegate that matches this subtype.
- Use as you would any other custom event in your code (also covered in that link).

Comment: you are free to create `RoutedEventHandler<T>` your self with a blink of an eye.. :)